# Disable AppCenter automatic searching to prevent freezes

Tags: user-interface, appcenter, search

I've recently installed eOS Loki and I'm annoyed with its AppCenter.

After entering 2 letters in the searchbox, it freezes for over 5 seconds because it searches those 2 letters in all apps database. Meanwhile, as I usually know what do I want to search, that means waiting. By the way, the results from 2-letters search probably won't be useful ever.

So, is there a way to stop automatic searching (so I would press Enter after writing something in search box, I always do that anyway) or increase the limit (so it would start searching at 4 entered characters, when it doesn't cause lags)?

Comment: related: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/9437/170