# App center crashes when typing into search bar

Tags: appcenter

I just installed Loki on my HP-G62 laptop. Everything seems to work ok except for one issue:

When I open AppCenter, and type just two letters into the search bar (any two), it exits.

My guess is that maybe the AppCenter is designed to start auto-searching for packages once it receives the first two characters, but it crashes instead. I don't see a settings menu to disable the auto search feature, leaving me to just comb through everything to find what I'm looking for.

Any advice is appreciated.

---

If run in terminal this happens:

```
~$ appcenter
[INFO 10:43:59.568658] Application.vala:155: App Center version: 0.1.2
[INFO 10:43:59.568717] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 4.4.0-51-generic
[FATAL 10:44:05.366387] Client.vala:429: Update_cache: Refesh cache async failed - W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexey-smirnov/deadbeef/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.W: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I'm having this problem as well.

Comment: I have the same issue. Earlier this day, no issues to notice. About a half hour ago I notice the same problem. At first I thought I broke it since I'm experimenting a lot, until I saw this post. Maybe the server is returning a bad query which causes the app to crash?

Comment: The same. It occured two or three hours ago.

Comment: Been having the exact same issue. Haven't encountered it at all when using Loki in the past, and I only just did a fresh install a few hours ago and everything was working fine. After an update, just typing in two letters crashes the AppCenter. Clicking on the categories works.

Comment: Open AppCenter via command line and try using it. When it crashes post what is shown.

Comment: Good call. I tried that, I get "Segmentation Fault"

Funny story is, it only happens with TWO characters. If I mash 3 or more into the search bar before it has the chance to crash, it works just fine.

Comment: @Jaydemir - It also crashes if you type three letters or more and then delete to just 2

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug reported on Launchpad here : [AppCenter crashes when typing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1646020). The two-character crash is mentioned.